# Font-family rule and its interpretation

Tags: html, css, fonts

My question does not have any code. So please do not ask me for it.
This is rather an informative question.

We all know about the CSS font-family rule. Ex

```
h1{font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;}
```

Now i understand that the reason to declare a font-family is that incase the browser fails to find the first font it will switch to the second. But in what scenarios does this happen. Does the failing of fonts have anything to do with fonts installed on the end users machine OR Certain browsers do not provide support for specific fonts?

Comment: Mostly, yes: if the first font is not installed on the system then use the second font. There are some more rules though...

Comment: Yeah. Thats my question. In what scenarios does this happen. The first part has been answered on SO

Comment: [This page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html) for instance says "it is not a simple problem to map typical font selection properties to a specific font." and explains some of the issues browsers have to face. I can copy some of the material from that page and paste it in an answer here if you like...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the answer is *YES*, the above declaration is used as a fall back if some or the other fonts fail to load. Let me explain you how.

Let us modify your declaration a bit. Assume that we have one web font and two system font, so declaration goes like

```
h1 {
   font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, Helvetica;
}
```

Here, we are fetching the `Open Sans` fonts from `Google Web Fonts`. So here, suppose the Google server is down or say the user browser is too old to understand the `font-face` or `Web Fonts`, and when my web page is requested by a particular user, the `Open Sans` font will fail to render as it isn't downloaded because the server is down, in this case, CSS will use `Arial`, now if the user System doesn't have `Arial` font, it will than apply `Helvetica`.

If the user has none of the fonts, than the website will render the user set browser default fonts.

Comment: Which one? Your example doesn't have one of the default fonts.

Comment: Ok, But in case the user does not have the Arial font installed doesnt the browser try to get this from the web?

Comment: @AnaMaria No it won't, browser will only fetch the web fonts if the user has defined using `@font-face` in his stylesheet. And also, *web fonts !=  system fonts*.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious scenario is a system that lacks the first font. In the unlikely event that Times New Roman is missing, Times is tried, and in practice it would probably be missing too, so `serif`, the browser’s default serif font, would then be used.

But the full picture is more complicated. Section [Font Matching Algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-matching-algorithm) in CSS Fonts Module Level 3 LC (which is in this respect more realistic, closer to browser reality, than CSS 2.1 specification) describes how the font is selected.

For example, consider this rule:

```
p { font-family: Arial Unicode MS, Arial; font-style: italic }
```

In this case, Arial will be used, because Arial Unicode MS has no italic typeface. Or at least this is what should happen by the book and what happens in modern browsers.

It is possible that the text contains a character that is not present in the primary font. Then the other fonts are tried, in order, to find a font that has the character. For the case given, `h1{font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;}`, this means that for any special or “foreign” characters not available in Times New Roman (or Times, but if present it probably has a more limited character repertoire), `serif` is used.